# how arrays are treated by gcc [ question related to C programing ]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, compiler-construction

This compiles in gcc with no errors or warnings even with -Wall option
meaning that array bounds are checked at run-time and hence compiler can't detect the error

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int a[2][3][4];

      a[1][2][100] = 4 ;

      return 0;
}
```

However,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int a[2][3];

      a[1][2][100] = 4 ;

      return 0;
}
```

this generates an error while compiling as :

```
$ gcc sample.c -Wall
sample.c: In function ‘main’:
sample.c:7: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

Why is this so ? in both the two codes a[1][2][100] is invalid . Still how can the compiler detect this is code2 and not in code1.

Specially when every compiler flattens all multidimensional array into corresponding single dimension arrays, then how can the compiler be selectively aware of this flaw in the code.

Explanation or mention of some book or article where the proper explanation resides will be gratefully accepted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the types. C does no bounds checking but it does do (static) type checking. The type of a in your first example is `int[][][]` but the type in the second example is `int[][]`.

The "flattening" that you refer to happens in code generation, which is (conceptually, at least) after type checking.

Comment: Is this because int [][] is actually int** and int [][][] is int*** ?

Comment: @SK `int*` and `int[]` are slightly different. Former implies static allocation (data segment, etc) while latter implies dynamic allocation (heap).

Comment: No. It's because you can subscript an int[] with an int, but you can't subscript an int with an int. If you subscript an int[][][] with an int you get an int[][]. If you subscript that with an int you get an int[]. If you subscript that with an int you get an int.  If you subscript that with an int you get a type error.

Comment: As an aside, the reason I keep saying "with an int" is because you actually can subscript an int with an array. There's no real reason to ever do this, though, so best not to think about it... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

First, array bounds are not checked at runtime or at compile time.  Be careful out there.

Second, your second case gives an error because you have a mismatch in array dimension - you're using three subscript operators (`[]`) on a 2D array.  Just because the array happens to be laid out in memory as an array of arrays doesn't mean there is any actual type changing going on with the variable.

Array subscripting is described in the C standard section **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**.

Comment: If all arrays are flattened by the compiler how can it discriminate between 2D or 3D arrays.

Comment: @S..K, there's no special case.  You can have arrays of any type. "3D" arrays are just arrays of "2D" arrays, etc.  All indexing is based on pointer arithmetic, which takes into account the size of the object (which again, may be an array).

Comment: The compiler must know the the shape of the array.  All dimensions except the last must be declared.  ex. arr[5][6][].  That's necessary and sufficient to interpret the array.

Comment: The internal implementation details of the array have nothing to do with the type of the variable.  You are trying to treat a 2D array like a 3D array, and that won't work.  You could do some funky typecasting to hack around it, but that's definitely not recommended.  As you noticed, the compiler doesn't care about you accessing memory outside of the array, but it does care about types, and that's where your problem is in example 2.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
int a[2][3];
```

the compiler will determine that `a[1][2]` is of type `int`. Therefore, accessing element `[100]` of this is equivalent to:

```
int x;
x[100] = 4;
```

This would give you the same error about the subscripted value.